# Custom post query with multiple fields with number values. Totalisation needed

Tags: custom-post-types

The following code gives me several tables (sorted by category) with custom fields and number values. What I need now, is a totalisation at the end of every table. How can I do that? Thanks!

```
 <div class="togglecontent"> <?php
$portraetrangliste = get_the_id();

  $catargs = array(
         'taxonomy'     => 'jahr',
        'order' => 'DESC',
  );
$cats = get_categories($catargs);

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'rangliste',
    'meta_key'      => 'portrait_nid',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_value'    =>  $portraetrangliste,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'jahr',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $cat->cat_ID,
        ),
    ),
);
global $post;
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?> <h5>Saison <?php echo $cat->cat_name ; ?> </h5>
  <table class="portraetrangliste">
    <tr>
      <th>Rang</th>
      <th>Kranz</th>
      <th>Sieger</th>
      <th>Jahreswertung<br />Punkte</th>
      <th>Bezwungene <br /> Eidgenossen </th>
      <th>Datum / Fest</th>
    </tr> <?php

   while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?> <tr>
      <td>
        <strong> <?php the_field( 'rang' ); ?> </strong>
      </td>
      <td> <?php if ( get_field( 'kranzgewinn' ) == 1 ) : ?> <?php echo 'Ja'; ?> <?php else : ?> <?php echo 'Nein'; ?> <?php endif; ?> </td>
      <td> <?php if ( get_field( 'sieger' ) == 1 ) : ?> <?php echo 'Ja'; ?> <?php else : ?> <?php echo 'Nein'; ?> <?php endif; ?> </td>
      <td> <?php the_field( 'punkte_jahresliste' ); ?> </td>
      <td> <?php the_field( 'bezwungene_eidgenossen' ); ?> </td>
      <td> <?php global $post; ?> <?php $fest_nid = get_field( 'fest_nid' ); ?> <?php if ( $fest_nid) : ?> <?php $post = $fest_nid; ?> <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?> <?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?> - <a href="
                    
                    
                    <?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a> <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> <?php endif; ?> </td>
    </tr> <?php
   endwhile; ?>
  </table> 
 <?php endif; 

// Added this now 
wp_reset_query() ; 
}
?></div>
```

[image]